# Laravel 5.3 - Como alterar a senha de um usuário logado?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com dificuldade para criar um método que me possibilite disponibilizar um formulário de alteração de senha para usuários logados. Gostaria de utilizar para isso os métodos da classe:  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController.

Atualmente tenho uma view com 3 campos, sendo eles:

- senha_atual
- nova_senha
- nova_senha_confirmation

No controller tenho um método com o código para efetuar a validação dos dados recebidos e persistir estes em banco:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
                                'senha_atual' => 'required|min:8',
                                'nova_senha' => 'required|min:8|confirmed']);

    if (!Hash::check($request->senha_atual, Auth::user()->password))
    {
        return redirect('/painel/alterarSenha')->withErrors(['senha_atual' => 'Senha incorreta'])->withInput();;
    }

    $resultado = $request->user()->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('nova_senha'))
    ])->save();

    if($resultado)
    {
        return redirect('/painel')->with(['success' => 'Senha alterada com sucesso!']);
    }
```

Mas como já mencionei, gostaria de utilizar os métodos do controlar ResetPasswordController que estende de Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords, até mesmo para seguir uma abordagem sólida e sem duplicação de código.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o Hash::check conforme usaste, para mim serviu.

```
 public function updateOwn(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $input = $request->all();

        if (! Hash::check($input['password_old'],Auth::user()->password)){
            return redirect('users/edit_own')->withErrors(['password' => 'Senha atual está incorreta'])->withInput();
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $input['id'],
            'password'   => ["required"],
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('users/edit_own')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
        $user = $this->users->find($id);

        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);//criptografa password

        $user->update($input);
        flash()->success('Usuário atualizado com sucesso. - '.$user->name);//flash message teste
        return redirect()->route('/home');
    }
```

O usuário só consegue alterar seus dados se confirmar a senha anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Mas já tentaste usar esse método? 
Normalmente eu faço exactamente da maneira que fizeste em cima e só uso o método ResetPassword para os utilizadores que perderam a senha.

Acho que a maneira que queres usar não vai funcionar porque o método Resetpassword tem um middleware('guest') que vai fazer com que o user seja redireccionado se estiver logado.

Já agora se descubriste uma maneira melhor de o fazer diz, pois sou novo na área e queria conhecer outros métodos.

Espero que tenha sido útil, abraço.

Comment: Eduardo, ainda estou vendo esta questão. Mas vamos trocar algumas ideias, me procura em http://github.com/fabiojaniolima